# List highest number inside all text files (multiple text files in directory)

Tags: php, bash, list, cron, webserver

I have a directory with multiple text files.
For example:

```
name1.txt
name2.txt
name3.txt 
etc.. etc..
```

Each text file holds 1 line, on that line is a number i.e "10"

I was wondering if it'd be possible to somehow echo back the text file names of say the top 10 highest numbers of all the text files.

I was wondering if this could be done live via PHP or updated periodically via a bash script / cron
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most efficient idea but assuming you can't use a DB (otherwise you probably would):

```
<?php
  $files = scandir('path/to/files/directory');
  $rows = Array();
  foreach($files as $file){
    array_push($rows,file_get_contents('path/to/files/directory/'.$file);
  }
  arsort($rows);
  $i = 0;
  foreach($rows as $key => $row){
    if($i <= 10){
       echo 'On '.$files[$key].' the number is'.$row;
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect, quick question. Is it possible to list the number in the file next to the output? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
grep . name*.txt | sort -nr -k2 | head -n 3
```

Output (e.g.):

```
name4.txt:1
name3.txt:123
name2.txt:444
```

Answer (score 0):

With bash.

First, create some files:

```
for n in $(seq 20); do echo $RANDOM > name${n}.txt; done
```

Now, top 5:

```
$ for f in *; do printf "%s\t%d\n" "$f" $(<$f); done | sort -k2nr | head -n 5
name16.txt  30283
name12.txt  29976
name8.txt   28948
name4.txt   28256
name6.txt   28148
```

Just the filenames

```
$ for f in *; do printf "%s\t%d\n" "$f" $(<$f); done | sort -k2nr | head -n 5 | cut -f1
name16.txt
name12.txt
name8.txt
name4.txt
name6.txt
```